# Sending data between wifi devices without them to be necessarily connected in the same network

Tags: android, esp8266

I've looking for ways to send data between wifi devices without them to be necessarily connected in a network. I've found that [ESP-Now](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj6l6LM2v_RAhUCHJAKHXIMCxIQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fespressif.com%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fdocumentation%2Fesp-now_user_guide_en.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFmj5SG_IA9RFqoWClEZMlkxkxXAQ&sig2=egLMD4wZwixwUC0gGBSJqg) can accomplish that by setting a default wifi channel and sending a data packet to another device by it's MAC address. Epressif has an android app that seems to support esp-now found [here](https://github.com/EspressifApp/IOT-Espressif-Android) that I've been digging for while but I can't find how they actually do it, I wasn't able to debug it either because there's like 840 errors in it. I wish I knew the right words to find it in google I've through a lot of them without luck can you kindly tell me whether it's possible or not to make this ESP-Now communication like in Android? Can I send this packet of data to an ESP from android without having the phone to be disconnected from an AP?

I'd like to be able to communicate to my wifi device without it to be necessarily connected on the same network as my phone alleviating the time spent switching between networks. I didn't do the tests but I heard it takes 10 seconds to switch networks programmatically in android.

PS: I know that if switching channels also takes time I'd need the esp-device to figure what channel the phone and it's AP are using but I could simply find out by packet sniffing and channel sweeping.

Arduino esp-now example can be found [here](https://github.com/cho45/esp8266-esp-now-sample.git).

Comment: "I've looking for ways to send data between wifi devices without them to be necessarily connected in a network." So, have you looked at Mesh usage of ESP8266 ?

Comment: No I haven't. Thinking of it makes sense they make a mesh network on top of ESP-now it's very zigbee like but that's not my problem. I'd like to use my Android phone to set the channel and send a broadcast or just send a message referred by a mac address to another device and possibly without disconnecting my phone from the AP.

Comment: but thank you for the remminder cagdas I'll look for android mesh network there might be what I've been looking for.

Comment: put the ESP in AP+STA; the STA on the same wifi as the phone, and other devices on the ESP's AP.

Comment: The STA cannot be on the same Wifi as the phone, they must be in different networks.